# Convertir string a entero, digito por digito

Tags: java, string

El codigo que ingreso es 8412584512541

El ultimo numero es decir el 1 debe ser ignorado. En el array numPosicionesPares deberia devolver -->8+1+5+4+1+5 y  numPosicionesImpares deberia devolver -->4+2+8+5+2+4. Que pasa? El array de impares me lo devuelve correctamente, pero al de los pares me devuelve el ultimo numero tambien,  Y NO deberia aparecer. Pero si hago cambios en el buble for para evitar esa ultima posicion me crashea los dos arrays (numPosicionesPares ,numPosicionesImpares ) y me los rellena con basura

```
public boolean validarCodBarras(String codBarras) {
        boolean codigoValidado = false;
        
        int[] numPosicionesPares = new int[6];
        int[] numPosicionesImpares = new int[6];
        int sumaPar = 0, sumaImpar = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;

        char[] codBarrasDescompuesto = codBarras.toCharArray();
        
        for (int i = 0; i <codBarrasDescompuesto.length; i++) {
            
            //asignamos a la cadena El string del codigo de barras
            if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                //System.out.println("POSICIONES PARES:-->"+codBarrasDescompuesto[i]);
                numPosicionesPares[j] = codBarrasDescompuesto[i];
                //paso 1
                sumaPar+=numPosicionesPares[j];
                j++;

            } else {
                //System.out.println("POSICIONES IMPARES:-->"+codBarrasDescompuesto[i]);
                numPosicionesImpares[k] = codBarrasDescompuesto[i];
                //paso2
                sumaImpar+=numPosicionesImpares[k];
                k++;
            }
        }

        // paso 3
        int multiSumaImpar = sumaImpar * 3;
        // paso 4
        int sumaParMasMulti = (sumaPar + multiSumaImpar);
        // paso 5
        int sumaParMasMultiRedondeado = (int) Math.ceil(sumaParMasMulti);
        int digitoDeControl = sumaParMasMultiRedondeado - sumaParMasMulti;
        if (codBarrasDescompuesto[12] == digitoDeControl) {
            codigoValidado = true;
        }
        return codigoValidado;
    }
```

Comment: ohhh muchas gracias!

Comment: si, es cierto, no se porque pero se me sigue rompiendo en el bucle for, añadi otro con una extension de 6 para tratar los otros vectores, pero sigo teniendo inconvenientes

Answer (score 1):

Debes tener cuidado cuando tienes arreglos limitados; en tu caso tienes un arreglo con **límite 6** que se encuentra en un `for` que recorre **13 veces**; entonces vas a tener un error porque no hay posiciones `> 6`.

Puedes utilizar índices diferentes para los arreglos con límite `[6]`. En el siguiente código utilizo `j` y `k` para esos arreglos:

```
numPosicionesPares[j];
numPosicionesImpares[k];
```

Y sumas en 1 el índice: `j++;`

Entonces quedaría así:

```
String codBarras = "1234567890123";
    
    boolean codigoValidado = false;
    int[] cadenaOriginal = new int[13];
    int[] numPosicionesPares = new int[13];//Aumenté el tamaño
    int[] numPosicionesImpares = new int[13];//Aumenté el tamaño
    int sumaPar = 0,sumaImpar=0, j=0,k=0;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < cadenaOriginal.length; i++) {
        //asignamos a la cadena El string del codigo de barras
        cadenaOriginal[i] = Integer.parseInt(codBarras.substring((i - 1), (i - 1) + 1));
        if ((i % 2) == 0) {
            numPosicionesPares[j] = cadenaOriginal[i];
            //paso 1
            sumaPar+=numPosicionesPares[j];
            j++;
        } else {
            numPosicionesImpares[k] = cadenaOriginal[i];
            //paso2
            sumaImpar+=numPosicionesImpares[k];
            k++;
        }
    }
    
    int multiSumaImpar= sumaImpar * 3;
    //paso 4
    int sumaParMasMulti = (sumaPar + multiSumaImpar);
    //paso 5
    int sumaParMasMultiRedondeado = (int) Math.ceil(sumaParMasMulti);   
    int digitoDeControl = sumaParMasMultiRedondeado-sumaParMasMulti;
    if(cadenaOriginal[12] == digitoDeControl) {
        codigoValidado = true;
    }
    System.out.println(codigoValidado); //Imprime false
```

Otra observación es aquí: `cadenaOriginal[12]` ojo con el límite que como lo tienes con 13 te da error.

Comment: Estoy probandolo pero aun asi me carga con basura los array de numeros en posiciones pares y los de impares

Comment: Sigue estando mal...
Este es mi codigo de barras 8412584512541... EL 1 del final debe ser ignorado, mas alla de su posicion.
Cuando me fijo los pares me arroja 815415 1 1 1 y deberia arrojar 815415
y en los impares me arroja 42852401, el 0 y el 1 sobran y no se tampoco de donde salen. Yo ya achique los arrays y los hice de 6

Comment: Nono, es que necesito hacerlo con la posicion par e impar!

Comment: En el `for` inicias en 0 y es considerado un número par, por eso las inconsistencias; debes empezar desde 1. Edité la respuesta con pares: 4285240 y en impares: 0154150

Comment: ahi edite la pregunta para que veas mas claro lo que te quiero decir, perdon si te maree!

Comment: no bro, no hace lo que debe :/

Comment: Tengo el resultado que pusiste en el comentario. Puedes darle un vistazo al código en modo debug y ver el resultado.

Answer (score 1):

El array de impares te lo devuelve bien porque tu array de entrada se conforma de 13 elementos (8412584512541) por lo que en tu ultima iteración del `for` tu **i** va a ser igual a 12 y no lo va a considerar para impar pero si para par.

Dicho esto, si lo que querés es evitar pasar por el ultimo numero del array de entrada (ignorar el 1 final tanto para par e impar) lo que podés hacer es recorrer en el bucle for todos los elementos menos el último. Esto lo podes limitar en la declaración misma del for restandole 1 al tamaño total del array en la comparacion

`for (int i = 0; i < (codBarrasDescompuesto.length -1); i++)`

De esta manera cuando i se haya incrementado a 12 la expresión `12 < (13 - 1)` no se va a cumplir y no va a seguir iterando.

Contestando a otra cosa que dijiste:

> Pero si hago cambios en el buble for para evitar esa ultima posicion me crashea los dos arrays (numPosicionesPares ,numPosicionesImpares ) y me los rellena con basura

No se que estabas intentando pero con la palabra reservada `break`podes cortar la iteración. Podrías usar un condicional dentro del codigo para cuando el **i** este en la ante ultima posición

```java
if(i == cadenaOriginal.length -2 ){ 
// que i sea 11 en tu ejemplo, porque el array va a tener  13 elementos
    break;
}
```